# Does an iphone6 have a front-camera flash

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation

When I set the flashmode for my front camera and then call

let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: process)
I get the following error message:

error while capturing still image: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x12eeb7200 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16800 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16800), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}

If I don't set the camera's flashMode and then call:

```
let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: process)
```

The front camera takes a picture and doesn't throw the error. So I wonder, does a front-camera flash exist for iphones. It should considering that  snapchat has one. And the default camera app on an iPhone has a front camera flash. So I'm not entirely sure what's going on. Currently, this is how I set up my camera:

```
func getCameraStreamLayer() -> CALayer? {

captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
currentCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
stillImageOutput!.outputSettings = [ AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG ]

if let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera) as AVCaptureDeviceInput{
    if captureSession!.canAddInput(input) && captureSession!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
        captureSession!.addInput(input)
        captureSession!.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
    }
}

return AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
```

}

```
func toggleFlash() {
    flash = !flash
    if flash {
        for case let (device as AVCaptureDevice) in AVCaptureDevice.devices()  {
            if device.hasFlash && device.flashAvailable {
                if device.isFlashModeSupported(.On) {
                    do {
                        try device.lockForConfiguration()
                        device.flashMode = .On
                        device.unlockForConfiguration()


                    } catch {
                        print("Something went wrong")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }else {//turn off flash
    }
}


func photograph(process: (CMSampleBuffer!,NSError!)->()) {
    let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: process)

}
    func flipCamera() {
    guard let session = captureSession where session.running == true else {
        return
    }

    session.beginConfiguration()
    let currentCameraInput = session.inputs[0] as! AVCaptureDeviceInput
    session.removeInput(currentCameraInput)


    let newCamera = {
        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        for case let device as AVCaptureDevice in devices {
            if(device.position == .Front && currentCameraInput.device.position == .Back){
                return device
            }
            if(device.position == .Back && currentCameraInput.device.position == .Front){
                return device
            }
        }
        return nil
    }() as AVCaptureDevice?
    currentCamera = newCamera!
    if let newVideoInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: newCamera) {
        captureSession?.addInput(newVideoInput)
    }

    captureSession?.commitConfiguration()
}
```

I'm not sure what I should do. I've tried to create a new capture session and then lock and then set the flashMode for the camera. I still get the same error.

Comment: this question doesn't even make sense if you are testing this on an actual device.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand you. I just want to use iphone's retina flash/true tone flash for the front camera. What part didn't make sense to you? I followed apple's documentation for turning flash on for a camera. Then I got an error. I don't know where to begin with debugging. So i'm just trying to ask as many questions as I can. My apologies if it doesn't make sense. Anyway, can you offer assistance at all? Have you made an app with camera functionality? It's funny, I've seen a bunch of tutorials for creating camera apps but they never seem to implement flash.

Comment: Or, do you know where I can look up those error codes?

Comment: @SamB any thoughts? Have you made a camera with front flash? Is it better to use uiviews?

Comment: Thank you @SamB for your time. I'm just going to assume that there is no flash available for the front camera EVEN THOUGH hasflash returns true for the front camera. Setting that property just causes a lot of problems. So I'll do it another way or forget it altogether

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 6 does not have a front facing flash camera, however the iPhone 6s and up does.

There are "hack" solutions in the app store that flash the screen brightly to generate light in front facing mode, but there's no actual flash.

Comment: My 6s flashes the screen

Comment: Ok Thank you very much! So then is the AVFoundation documentation wrong? Should this be reported to apple? AVFoundation has something called hasFlash and it returns true for the front camera. That's a bug in this case. How do you report bugs.